# How to add two models in one page Django

Tags: python, django

When i try to add two models in one page it doesn't work and return the html code:[image]

How can i add to the one page two models?

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    home_results = MainPageInfo.objects.all();
    context_home = {'home_results': home_results}
    navigation_results_hone = Navigation.objects.all();
    context_navigation_home = {'navigation_results_hone': navigation_results_hone}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context_home, context_navigation_home)
```

**models.py**

```
class Navigation(models.Model):
    title = models.FileField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d', blank = False, verbose_name=' SVG')

class MainPageInfo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Info')
```

**admin.py**

```
admin.site.register(Navigation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render` accepts only one [context variable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render). Therefore, you need to pass everything via one variable:

```
def home(request):
    home_results = MainPageInfo.objects.all();
    navigation_results_hone = Navigation.objects.all();
    context = {'home_results': home_results, 'navigation_results_hone': navigation_results_hone}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```